# Inapp response goes purchased even the payment is in pending in user purchase history

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

Do there any chance of getting purchased response from apple for pending transaction. The in-app purchase history of the user shows the transaction in pending state but our paymentcompleted method invokked .

Comment: What payment completed method? Where? In your app code?  On your server? When do you call that method?  Is it possible to call that method without calling `completeTransaction`? What if you mark the payment complete but the network failed during `completeTransaction`? Then you could have an incomplete transaction sitting in the queue.  Does your app process pending transactions on launch?  Can you show relevant code?

Answer (score 2):

You can check for receipt in the app bundle using

```
NSData *aData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];
```

if data is present then validate the receipt with app store 
for sandbox mode
@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
for production mode
@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"

```
NSString *encodedReceipt = [aData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSError *error;
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"receipt-data":encodedReceipt,@"password":@"inapp_pwd"};
```

Http method POST

check this response you will get the status